# Denormalizing Data (Maybe A Pivot?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table containing Student Numbers and corresponding Teacher Numbers, and I need to denormalize it for input to a legacy system.

For example, here's what the data looks like now:

```
StudNumber  TeacherNumber
445        57315
445        88584
445        95842
858        88115
858        65443
858        57315
858        21144
858        18657
858        88584
311        64521
665        35512
665        57315
665        15546
```

What I'd like it to look like is this, splitting out each Teacher into a separate column, filling columns from left-to-right. One business rule is that each student can have no more than six teachers:

```
StudNum Teacher1    Teacher2    Teacher3    Teacher4    Teacher5    Teacher6
445     57315       88584        95842
858     88115       65443        57315      21144        18657      88584
311     64521
665     35512       57315        15546
```

There are 10,000+ rows in the original table, so I need to do this programatically. 
Thank you!

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the 7th+ teacher and how do you determine which ones are 1-6?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one is 1-6, as long as they're filled left-to-right. There won't ever be more than 6 providers per student, due to business rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use pivot. You also need to "Rank" your teachers 1-6. See my comment on how you want to do this. For now:

```
Select StudNumber, TeacherNumber, TeacherRank
from (
   Select ST.StudNumber
       , ST.TeacherNumber
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ST.StudNumber 
                    ORDER BY ST.TeacherNumber) AS TeacherRank
   From StudentTeacher AS ST)
Where TeacherRank <=6
```

Then you can pivot on this statement. Here is a good explanation: [Using Pivot and UnPivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed -- to rank them so I could pivot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The old school method is to use [CASE expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx); since SQL Server 2005 you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

CASE example:

```
SELECT t.studnumber,
       CASE WHEN t.teachernumber = 57315 THEN t.teachernumber ELSE NULL END AS TEACHER1,
       CASE WHEN t.teachernumber = 88115 THEN t.teachernumber ELSE NULL END AS TEACHER1
```

But dynamically placing a given teachernumber as teacher1/etc is an entirely different matter.

Comment: This is what pivot does under-the-hood w/o the "black magic" and special syntax...

Answer (score 1):

I second PIVOT.

Here are two interesting links with programmatic solutions to dynamic crosstab data in SQL.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/crosstab-pivot-table-workbench/

Comment: Changed "dinamic" to "dynamic".