# Please explain the parts of a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have read lots of blog posts.  I have read the docs.  I am usually fairly good at picking up new stuff but even though I keep reading, but I just don't understand the parts of a PIVOT in SQL Server (2008).

Can someone please give it to me, nice and slow.  (ie Pivot for Dummies)

If an example is needed then we can use the one [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440789/transform-sql-query-results).

Here is how I tried to pivot that example:

```
SELECT OtherID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5
FROM 
    (SELECT OtherID, Val
    FROM @randomTable) p
PIVOT
(
    max(val)
    FOR Val IN (Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5)
) AS PivotTable;
```

The above query gives me nulls instead of values in the Val1, Val2... columns.

But to be clear, **I am not looking for a fixed query here**.  I need to **understand** PIVOT as I am looking to pivot something far more complex than this example.

Specifically what is the deal with the aggregate?  I just want to take all string values that match on a given ID and put them in the same row.  I am not trying to aggregate anything.  (Again, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440789/transform-sql-query-results) for my example.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Explanation of the pivot query

```
FROM 
    (SELECT OtherID, Val, amount
    FROM @randomTable) p
```

These are the columns that become the "base data" for the pivot.  Do not include columns that don't do anything.  Just as you don't put non-GROUP BY columns into the SELECT clause, you don't list out unused columns in a PIVOT source.

```
PIVOT
(
    max(amount)
    FOR Val IN (Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5)
) AS PivotTable;
```

This part says that you are creating 5 new columns named "Val1" through "Val5".  These column names represent **values** in the column Val.  So it is expected that your table will contain something like this

```
otherID   Val     amount
1         Val1    1
2         Val2    2
1         Val3    3
1         Val1    5
(etc)     (this column contains one of Val1 - Val5, or null)
```

So you now have 5 new columns that did not exist before.  What goes into the column?

- Any column that appears in the OUTPUT that is not a PIVOTed column is a "GROUP BY" column.
- The aggregate function is what collects all the data into the cell that is the CROSS between the GROUP BY columns and the PIVOTED column.

So, to illustrate, using the sample data above, we have otherID=1 and val=Val1.  In the output table, there is only one cell representing this combination of Max(amount) for each (otherID/val) combination

```
otherID   Val1   Val2   Val3   Val4   Val5
1         <x>    ...    ...    ...    ...
(etc)
```

For the cell marked `<x>` , only one value is allowed, so `<x>` cannot contain multiple `amount` values. That is the reason why we need to aggregate it, in this case using `MAX(amount)`.  So in fact, the output looks like this

```
(unpivoted columns)   (pivoted, creates "new" columns)
otherID             |  Val1          Val2           Val3   Val4   Val5
1                   |  MAX(amount)   Max(amount)    << cell value = aggregate function
(etc)
```

The SELECT statement is what then outputs these columns

```
SELECT OtherID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5
```

Comment: That is an awesome explanation!  I get it now.  The big thing I was missing was that the new columns names have to be existing values.

Comment: I also realize that this means I can't use pivot.  (I don't know the column names to pivot on before hand.)

Comment: @Vaccano Search SO or Google for "sql server dynamic pivot". It builds a dynamic SQL statement that makes use of PIVOT (or the old style `MAX(CASE` pivoting).

Comment: @Vaccano: Yes you can, if you use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function just like [Martin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440789/transform-sql-query-results/5444615#5444615) has suggested.

Comment: "Any column that appears in the OUTPUT that is not a PIVOTed column is a "GROUP BY" column". This is what I was missing. My `PIVOT` was working but I had no idea why! There's an implicit `GROUP BY`.